# Why is my div swallowing the one before it?

Tags: html, css

I have a message div with an orange background listing a message on the screen when someone logs out, but for some reason it eats the div before it so they're both in the same box. What gives? I keep looking at it, but can't figure out what's going on.

Link: http://goodpricescome.com?logout=1

The code is simple:

```
<div id="motto">A website for those who wait</div>
<?php if ($error) echo "<div class='error'>$error</div>"; ?>
<?php if ($warning) echo "<div class='warning'>$warning</div>"; ?>
```

Stylesheets:

```
    #motto {
        font-size       : 20px;
        font-weight     : bold;
        margin-top      : 20px;
        font-family     : Shadows Into Light Two,Sans-Serif;
        text-align      : center;
        position        : static;
        width           : 100%;
        margin-bottom   : 35px;
    }
    .warning, .error {
        width           : 500px;
        margin-bottom   : 15px;
    }
```

Comment: You have defined `float : left;` for `#motto` in line 891 of `styles.css`.

Comment: Add `clear: left;` to `.warning, .error`

Comment: Thank you! I just wasn't seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the float. Please refer [CSS 101: Block Formatting Contexts](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/05/19/css-101-block-formatting-contexts/).

You might not need the `float: left` to the `#motto`, if at all it is required please clear the floats as suggested at [A new micro clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was something... but I just couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

This weird behavior happens because your `#motto` has a `float: left` property. You need to add `clear: both` to your `.warning, .error` еlement.